# Combining mean-values.

Tags: probability

Suppose I have machine that solves a certain type of problem in time T. T is not the same every time but depend upon a probability distribution $p(T)$. The average time $\langle{T}\rangle$ is calculated by the integral $\int_0^\infty Tp(T) dT$. Suppose I have N machines running in parallel. The running time follows the same probability distribution $p(T)$ for each machine.

The question is, what is the new mean-value $\langle{T}\rangle$ before I get the answer from anyone of the machines? As N tends to infinity obviously the new mean value $\langle{T}\rangle$ should tend to the lowest possible time T in the probability distribution for a single machine.

Comment: Your formula for average is missing a $T$.

Comment: What you're looking for is called an order statistic.  The basic idea is to work with the CDFs to write the probably that all machines exceed some time, $T$, then you can differentiate.  The formulas should be available via a search.

Comment: Can I think like this? 

The new mean will be calculated as follows:

I sum over the weighted probabilities that machine 1 will give me the answer after k steps provided it haven't happend already at some earlier time by any other machine. So i sum over the ordinary probabilities but multiply each probability in this sum with the probability that it haven't happend yet by any other of the machines.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably times are non-negative.

You can find the cumulative distribution function for each machine $$F(t) = \Pr(T \le t) = \int_{s=0}^t p(s) \, ds$$

Assuming the times on each machine are independent as well as being identically distributed, then the probability that all $n$ machines take more than $t$ is $(1-F(t))^n$ and this makes the expected time for at least one machine to stop $$\int_{r=0}^{\infty} (1-F(r))^n \, dr$$ and if you wan to test this with a specific distribution I would suggest the exponential with rate $\lambda$, which gives $p(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, $F(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$ and expectation of the minimum $\frac{1}{n \lambda}$, i.e. a rate of $n \lambda$

You are correct that if this expectation of the minimum time is finite then it will converge on the minimum of the support of $T$ as $n$ increases